# Yii2 query OR condition multiple values for 1 column

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I've made an API with the Yii2 framework.
But I don't know how to use the OR condition in my statement.

For example:
I want to get all cars with brand BMW or DODGE.

I've tried the following:

```
$query = Car::getCar($lang)
         ->where(['or', ['m.brand' => 'BMW'], ['m.brand' => 'DODGE']])
         ->all();
```

But this doesn't work.
I only get it to work with one value for m.brand.

So:

```
$query = Car::getCar($lang)
         ->where(['m.brand' => 'BMW'])
         ->all();
```

Works just fine.

Tried to put in a few other ways, but I don't get this to work.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The getCar method returns something like:

```
(new Query())->select(['a.auto_id'])->from('auto_new a')
```

**EDIT 2**
Got it to work with:

```
$query->andWhere(['or', ['m.brand' => 'BMW'], ['m.brand' => 'DODGE']])
```

Comment: This should work as long as static method `getCar()` returns `ActiveQuery` instance.

Comment: @Bizley I've added what the getCar returns. I don't think thats te problem, because a single where parameter for a single column works just fine

Comment: This is weird, it should work. What do you mean by "I don't get this to work"? Is there any error or you just don't see expected results? Please test this version with `or` by replacing `->all();` with `->createCommand()->rawSql;` and examining the output.

Comment: It only returns the all BMW's

Comment: Could you paste the result of this output?

Comment: I have rewritten the first query from your question using my own tables in exactly the same fashion and can confirm that it does indeed work for me. Are you sure there are no typos in the brand name and are you certain the getCar function is returning what you are expecting it to return?

Comment: Hmm I will make another script with only those orWheres to look if it works then

Comment: @WouterdenOuden why are you ignoring my request?

Comment: @Bizley sorry, I was busy. I will first try to make a new query with only the orWheres, because I think the query as it is now is not working. The result is a bit to large to post here also.

Comment: @WouterdenOuden I mean `rawSql` output. You can always use pastebin service.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1h9YrKtN this is what I get if I use ->where(['m.brand' => ['BMW', 'DODGE']]

Comment: I've fixed it by just making the query from scratch and started with the or statements. It works now.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually simplify it a lot by using an array with the values you need:

```
$query = Car::getCar($lang)
    ->where(['m.brand' => ['BMW', 'DODGE']])
    ->all();
```

This will execute with something like `WHERE m.brand IN ('BMW', 'DODGE')` which returns the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you well, you could use something like this:

```
Model::find()
             ->orWhere(['brand' => 'brand1'])
             ->orWhere(['id' => 'brand2'])
             ->all();
```

Comment: I've replaced the where with orWhere, but it still only returns the BMW's only.

Answer (score 2):

`where()` can take an array to create sql along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE brand in ('brand1', 'brand2');
```

using this construct you can generate an array of brands you wish to return then use the following ActiveQuery.

```
$brands = ['BMW', 'DODGE'];
$query = Car::find()->where(['brand' => $brands])->all();
```